# Debug has an indirect dependency on Android API level X, but minSdkVersion for variant 'debug' is API level Y

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have a Android project created with Android Studio.  I have added some third party dependencies to the project, but when I try to compile in Android Studio I hit the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.
> ERROR: Debug has an indirect dependency on Android API level 14, \
  but minSdkVersion for variant 'debug' is API level 8
```

Compiling on the command line with `./gradlew` works fine.

What does this error mean?

How do I fix it?

Many thanks.

---

UPDATE:

My top level build.gradle file:

```
[snowch@laptop MyApplication]$ cat build.gradle 
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://maven.restlet.org" }
    }
}
```

The application module's build.gradle:

```
[snowch@laptop MyApplication]$ cat app/build.gradle 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.snowch.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'net.christophersnow:sync-android-p2p:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    compile("org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:2.1-M7") {
        exclude group: 'org.osgi', module: 'org.osgi.core'
    }
    compile("org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.simple:2.1-M7")

}
```

Comment: in your `manifest.xml` set minimum sdk to 8, `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>`

Comment: @MurtazaHussain this value in the manifest is overrided by gradle.

Comment: Post your gradle's files.

Comment: I've updated the question with the build.gradle files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting the `minSdkVersion` to `14` in the `app\build.gradle` file fixed the issue for me.

Thanks to [murtaza-hussain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061944/murtaza-hussain) and [gabriele-mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) for the inspiration.